# Stateful web framework for dynamic applications

Tags: websocket, web-frameworks

Currently I use php + ajax to create dynamic web applications. As I realized, sometimes I need to write much more javascript to achieve dynamic appearance than I would need to write just php for 'static' page.
After small research I found websockets / sockets.io. Can I use it instead client-side javascript to achieve the same dynamics (some pagination, reloading website parts without reloading whole page...)?
Another thing is server-side programming language (and framework) for that task. Languages I've been working with:

1. Python (I would prefer that one)
2. Javascript / CoffeeScript
3. Java

Do you know any web framework written in one of those languages that fits my needs?

Answer (score 1):

Non blocking environments/frameworks you might want to take a look at.

- **JavaScript:** node.js
- **Python:** Twisted
- **Ruby:** EventMachine

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to reduce javascript ajax thus propose using websockets, it will not help u much. Maintaining socket is beneficial to avoid long polling ajax/rest requests, in your case it doesnt look like much if only to render  json for dynamic contents.
Also im not sure where does stateful exist in your requirements.
So stick with your architecure as is